# Verb "contribute to" + "doing something"

Tags: grammar, verb-forms

> I would like to contribute to arresting that man.

Is this grammatically correct? I mean to have an influence on / bring about arresting him.

Answer (score 7):

> I would like to **contribute** *to* **arresting** that man.

This is a grammatically correct sentence. It means that *the speaker would like to assist in arresting "that man".*

**Contribute** - *(Intransitive verb) to help to make something happen.*

**Example sentences -**

> 1. Medical negligence was said to have **contributed** *to* **her death**.
> 2. The scandal certainly **contributed** *to* **their defeat** at the last election.
> 3. The miracles that have **contributed** *to* **making** the film as good as it is are apparent every time I watch it.
> 4. Grime and pollution all **contribute** *to* **making** the hair look dull.
> 5. This now provides an excellent, free car park and will very usefully **contribute** *to* **reducing** traffic congestion in Haworth as a 'Park and Ride' facility.

Comment: Hello, MFI. I see that ELL has a similar explicit caveat to that on ELU: _Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!_ But I don't see any linked attribution. Where do your 'Example sentences' come from? A reputable dictionary? The internet? A  dodgy newspaper? A comic? Are they home-made?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth sorry I don't remember where I found those example sentences. Tomorrow I will try to add the source.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I looked upon OALD for that and found that *contribute to **do** something* in this context won't be something a native might prefer. That said, even if it is grammatically okay, it'll not look natural.

> I'd like to help arresting that man -looks natural over *contributing*

However, *your contribution* in arresting the culprit could be very useful for police. :)

Comment: I find contribution connects with "to", so it should be " your contribution to arresting... Am I right or your "in" is correct?

Comment: with its normal form *contribution*, *in* is [not incorrect](http://ianslive.in/index.php?param=news/Indian_armys_contribution_in_WWI_remembered_in_Brussels-450309/INTERNATIONAL/13).

Answer (score -1):

I would like to contribute some of my resources to reducing the increasing pollution around.

your contribution to reducing the increasing pollution is highly appreciable.

In above-given, sentences both verb and noun has been used with preposition "to"

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Take the [tour]. It seems like you've got the start of an interesting answer here, but it's not clear how verbs and nouns being used after "to" ensure that the original sentence is grammatical. Can you [edit] to clarify that?